# What does SQLcommandTimeout = -1 mean?

Tags: c#, sql, timeout

Recently I saw this value set in some projects, I will like to know what it exactly means, default or max allowed?

Comment: Let the queries run for as long as they want.  -1 in this context would generally mean no timeout.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the timeout is set to a value less than `1`, it will set the timeout to infinity: it waits forever until the command has been executed or failed.

Answer (score 1):

A likely reason for using -1 is that the author wanted a command with no timeout. However, the code should be changed to set timeout to zero, which means "no timeout" according to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?view=netframework-4.7.2):

> A value of 0 indicates no limit (an attempt to execute a command will wait indefinitely).

Depending on the implementation, setting a negative value for `CommandTimeout` may throw an exception. Here is an example from [Microsoft Reference Source cod](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.data/system/data/sqlclient/SqlCommand.cs)e:

```
override public int CommandTimeout { // V1.2.3300, XXXCommand V1.0.5000
    get {
        return _commandTimeout;
    }
    set {
        Bid.Trace("<sc.SqlCommand.set_CommandTimeout|API> %d#, %d\n", ObjectID, value);
        if (value < 0) {
            throw ADP.InvalidCommandTimeout(value);
        }
        if (value != _commandTimeout) {
            PropertyChanging();
            _commandTimeout = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd guess at don't timeout or infinity, the recommended way of doing this though is setting the value to 0 as shown here [SqlCommand.CommandTimeout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtimeout?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Data_SqlClient_SqlCommand_CommandTimeout)

Possibly done not knowing about setting the value to 0 would do the job.